# form.is_valid() is throwing error while using phone as primary key

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a mobile-otp login portal in Django. I changed the User model and made phone number a primary key, User class looks like this.

**Models.py**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(validators=[email_regex], max_length=50, blank=True)
    phone_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I am getting no errors while signing up the user. I am then sending the otp on the user's phone and when I am trying to validate the otp sent on the that phone, verify_form.is_valid() is throwing the error. I checked the error by using *messages.error(request, "Error")* and it shows **User with this Phone already exists.**

Below is the views.py, forms.py.

**Views.py**

```
#function used to signup the user and to send the otp on the phone.
def phonesignup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        phone_form = forms.PhoneSignupForm(request.POST)
        if phone_form.is_valid():
            user = phone_form.save(commit=False)
            phone = phone_form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            password = BaseUserManager().make_random_password(length=12)
            user.phone = phone
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            response = sendsmsotp(phone=phone)
            # more-code

# function to verify the otp 
def verifysmsotp(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        verify_form = forms.OTPVerifyForm(request.POST)
        print(verify_form)

        if verify_form.is_valid():   #<----------------------Form Error Here
            sent_otp = verify_form.cleaned_data.get('otp')
            phone = verify_form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            # more-code
```

**Forms.py**

```
class PhoneSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Mobile Number', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone',)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        phone = cleaned_data.get('phone')

        phone_q = User.objects.filter(phone=phone)
        if phone_q.exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Phone Already Present in Database')

        return cleaned_data


class OTPVerifyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    otp = forms.CharField(label='Enter OTP', required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Enter Mobile Number', required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('phone', 'otp')

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        phone = cleaned_data.get('phone')

        phone_q = User.objects.filter(phone=phone)
        if phone_q.exists():
            user = phone_q.first()
            if user.phone_verified:
                raise forms.ValidationError('Phone Already Verified')

        return cleaned_data    # returns phone and otp
```

Please help me get through this. If you need more info please let me know.

**Note:** I haven't tried changing the primary key to default user_id but I would do that after this post. It would be helpful if you come up with a solution where the phone is the primary key.

Comment: you are creating a user when he send a request for OTP. and when he comes back to verify OTP you have check that no user exist with that phone number, which will clearly violate in every attempt

Comment: @Sreeram and where _I am checking that no user exist with that phone number_ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OTPVerifyForm should be a plain Form, not a Model form.